# verb tense past simple or present perfect

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

1. We have a problem with your latest delivery - it ARRIVED 3 days late again.
2. We have a problem with your latest delivery - it HAS ARRIVED 3 days late again.

Which verb tense is correct?

Comment: Both are correct, but what do you want to imply? What is the context?

Comment: This is a sample text to practice customer complaints and my student asked me which tense was correct

Comment: Because it's *your **latest** delivery* we can assume that the delivery was ***very recent***. That same emphasis on "recency" is also conveyed by *it **has** arrived* (where it's very likely that text was written *on the actual day of delivery*). The Simple Past *it arrived 3 days late* could be used even if the most recent delivery was days, weeks, or even longer ago. In short, the only difference is that Present Perfect ***has arrived*** implies ***arrived just recently***.

Comment: Another problem with both candidate sentences is that the deliveries are late *again* . It's somewhat awkward to say that *A* delivery was late *again.* Also, if it's "your delivery" then it didn't passively "arrive." Maybe you want some variation on "you were late again with your latest delivery."

Comment: @puppetsock "Your delivery was late again" is natural for me. It's understood that it's not the same delivery being late twice.